# How do I dismiss a rootViewController before presenting a new UITabBarController?

Tags: ios, swift

I've set up a UIViewController as my rootViewController in AppDelegate, however, when a user logs in or skips it I am presenting a UITabBarController over the top.

I need to dismiss the LoginController, and set the UITabController as rootViewController instead after user logs in.

How can I go about reorganizing this?

AppDelegate()

```
window = UIWindow()
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
window?.rootViewController = LoginController()
```

LoginController()

```
self.present(MainTabBarController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: One time login view controller is one of the most commonly asked questions. Please search first.

Comment: Also: "I need to dismiss the LoginController, and set the UITabController as rootViewController instead after user logs in." No, you don't. There is absolutely nothing wrong with presenting the tab bar controller over the login view controller the first time, and never coming back to it. But on _subsequent_ launches of the app, you won't bother with the login view controller, as the user is already logged in.

Answer (score 1):

you can design your code like this.

[This one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cy093.png)

Answer (score 1):

It's too easy to maintain condition for user logged in or not, and then based on that status. You can navigate to your view.

You can try this way :

1.In `AppDelegate` you can these methods.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let isLogin = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "IS_LOGIN")
    if isLogin == true {
        self.goToDashboardView()
    } else {
        self.goToLoginView()
    }
    return true
}

//MARK:- ------- Global Methods -------

class func sharedInstance() -> AppDelegate {
    return UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
}

func goToLoginView() {

    let sb = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let loginVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
    let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: loginVC) // You can skip this if you do not want to add navigation bar
    self.window?.rootViewController = navVC // if you skipped above line, then you have to assign 'loginVC' here.
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}

func goToDashboardView() {

    let sb = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let tabbarVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyTabBarController") as! MyTabBarController
    self).window?.rootViewController = tabbarVC // if you skipped above line, then you have to assign 'loginVC' here.
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

2.In `LoginViewController`, when user logged in successfully.

```
@IBAction func btnLoginClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // Your API call or other code
    // If all things goes well, then login and go to dashboard

    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "IS_LOGIN")
    AppDelegate.sharedInstance().goToDashboardView()
}
```

3.And finally, whenever and from wherever you want to log out from app, just call below code.

```
@IBAction func btnLogOutClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // Your API call or other code
    // If all things goes well, then logout and go to login view

    UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "IS_LOGIN")
    AppDelegate.sharedInstance().goToLoginView()
}
```

4.And `Main.storyboard` should have design something like :
[image: TabBar in Storyboard]

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to present the UITabBarViewController and then dismiss the LoginViewController, you just need to reset the UITabBarViewController as a rootViewController for you app after login or skip as the following:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

// Override point for customization after application launch.

let yourTabBar = UIStoryboard(name: "YOUR_STORYBOARD_NAME", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YOUR_UITABBARCONTROLLER_ID")
self.window!.rootViewController = yourTabBar
self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
return true
}
```