# How to segue from UIPageViewController to a UINavigationController for iOS app onboarding

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I am creating an iOS app with an "onboarding" tutorial to be shown the first time a user uses the app. I have the tutorial set up as a UIPageViewController with a button to finish the tutorial. When this is pressed, I'd like to switch to my main navigation controller that handles the rest of the app. So far I have not found a good way to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56350233/how-do-i-dismiss-a-rootviewcontroller-before-presenting-a-new-uitabbarcontroller/56383231#56383231. Just replace `UITabBarController` with `UIPageViewController` and other things as per requirements.

Comment: This worked, thanks! Just had to rewrite it in objective c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've always coded these 'first time used' view controllers to be launched from the main navigation controller, which is designated as the start-up view controller.  When the main controller is being created, it checks for a flag to see if it is the first time, and if so, then segue to the first time used view controller. This happens so fast, usually, that you don't ever see the main controller first.  At the end of the first time use logic, clicking the done button just returns to its parent navigation controller, which then sets the first time flag to false.

Comment: I am able to start the application in the correct view based on if it's the user's first time, but am still not able to add the PageViewController to the main navigation controller or segue from the PageViewController to any view in the NavigationController. Maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: You should start the application in the main view controller ALL of the time.  That view controller should be defined in your Storyboard as the Start-Up view controller.  Then, you highlight your main view controller in the Storyboard, click and drag to the PageViewController to create the segue from Main to PageView called showPageView, then just have code in the ViewDidLoad (or other appropriate method) to check the flag and perform [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showPageView" sender:self];

Comment: Ah, I see. That helped! I was using the wrong view when I attempted your answer. Thanks for the follow up!