# Change root view controller in iOS 13 during runtime

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, rootviewcontroller

I use switchRootViewController in this [UIWindow extension](https://github.com/SwifterSwift/SwifterSwift/blob/master/Sources/SwifterSwift/UIKit/UIWindowExtensions.swift) to switch my root ViewController when the app shifts from register flow screens to Dashboard screen.

In iOS 13, this gives a blank screen. I've tried changing from `keyWindow` to `windows.first` as well. Still it is giving blank screen. Any idea how to fix this?

Note: I haven't added Scene delegate. My root view controller launches fine in the first launch. When I try to change it later on using that extension, then blank screen comes.

Answer (score -1):

Try my answer from this post : [How do I dismiss a rootViewController before presenting a new UITabBarController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56350233/how-do-i-dismiss-a-rootviewcontroller-before-presenting-a-new-uitabbarcontroller/56383231#56383231)

Just replace `MyTabBarController` with your `DashboardViewController`.

Comment: This is related to rootViewController switching in iOS 13.

Comment: You have asked question about that only. You want to change rootviewcontroller.... right?? This answer you can try.